# How to perform wait in uiPath in such a way that till the timeout it checks for the app state frequently

Tags: uipath-studio

Similar to Fluent Waits in Selenium, does uiPath has wait where I can mention overall timeout and polling frequency so that it would check the condition to be true till the overall timeout has not occurred.